# Pause Vimeo video on close in Custom Popup

Tags: javascript, iframe, popup, vimeo, pause

I have a vimeo video opening up in a lightbox. When closing the lightbox, the video will continue to play if it is not paused. I need to have the video pause once clicking out of the lightbox.

Here's what I've been able to come up with... But having trouble writing the JavaScript. Thanks in advance.

```
<a class="btn trigger" href="javascript:;">
   <img src="#">
</a>


<div id="videoFrame1" class="modal-wrapper">
    <div class="modal">
        <div class="head">
            <a class="btn-close trigger" href="javascript:;"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="js-video [vimeo, widescreen]">
                 <iframe id="firstvideo" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/291592533" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.trigger').click(function() {
     $('.modal-wrapper').toggleClass('open');
     return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: This should help:  How to pause Vimeo video in Javascript? 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33593360/how-to-pause-vimeo-video-in-javascript#33595192

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this issue is to integrate the [Vimeo player.js script](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js).  This has a method for pausing the player:

```js
var video = document.getElementById('firstvideo');
var player = new Vimeo.Player(video);

$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.trigger').click(function() {
     player.pause()
     return false;
  });
});
```